# keyWindow lost when call to start watching location in iOS APP

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, marketingcloudapi, mobilepush-ios

When we call to *sfmc_startWatchingLocation*, if we have location permissions granted, with the conditions details below, after assign window key:

```
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

its provokes to lose the reference when we accessed to it from our app:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
```

this answers nil, and we can not reassign it.

If we don't call to *sfmc_startWatchingLocation*, this problem never happens.

NOTE:  If location permissions have not been granted, the problem never happens either.

Please help me to solve this problem. If any further clarifications are required on this question please post a comment.

This error is provoking crashes in my app, and bad comments in Store.
Thanks

ERROR CONDITIONS:

Devices: iPhone 12pro(iOS15.3), iPhoneXR, ... (newest devices)

iOS version: iOS 15.3.1 (we had not detected it before)

Lib version: 'MarketingCloudSDK' version '7.3.1', integrated via cocoapods

Xcode version: tested in 12.1, 13.2, 13.2.1